# How to get Mason dhandler component name for query?

Tags: cgi, mason, psgi

Before handling a query, I'm trying to figure out if some component can actually handle it;

I'm trying to use

```
interp->comp_exists
```

but it does not return a dhandler component for the given query.

Is there some way to fetch such component?